# Error when I associate closed Incidents to a new incident Dynamics crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

When I try to associate a new incident with closed Incidents I have this message error:

"This case has already been resolved. Close and reopen the case record to see the updates."

here is the screenshot:
[image]

and here is the message error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: This case has already been resolved. Close and reopen the case record to see the updates.Detail:
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/.../Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220273</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="schemas.datacontract.org/.../System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>CallStack</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse, Boolean checkAdminMode)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, Boolean checkAdminMode)</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>This case has already been resolved. Close and reopen the case record to see the updates.</Message>
  <Timestamp>2015-09-14T13:37:51.4833346Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Do you have  any idea how I can fix this proble ?

thank you in advance !!

Comment: This is Dynamics CRM's built-in business logic doing its validations.

Answer (score 2):

the error message tells you exactly what to do to handle this issue.  Because the case is closed, it doesn't want you to make updates to it.  If you need to make changes, go ahead and reopen the case, and then re-close it if you are done.